# Different list of iOS simulator Xcode 7.1 and Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode7.2

I've recently installed Xcode 7.2. I've opened one project in Xcode 7.1 and same on Xcode 7.2. The simulator list in Xcode 7.2 is strange as compared to Xcode 7.1.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

When I try to run app on Xcode7.2 simulator it runs and quits silently.

Why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Xcode 7.1 and Xcode 7.2 are communicating with different instances of CoreSimulatorService, so they get out of sync.  I suspect you installed an older runtime and both running services created devices for the installed runtime (instead of just one).  Xcode then uses the UDID to disambiguate them.  This is discussed in more detail in multiple other questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

- click Add Additional Simulators
- you will see many same Simulators, delete the redundant ones, and solve it.